# How to get the universal dependency?

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

stanfordnlp/CoreNLP How to get the universal dependency, NOT enhanced just like the demo online from command line?

In "stanford-parser-full-2016-10-31", I try the command line:

`java -mx1000m -cp "$scriptdir/:" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -sentences newline -outputFormat "typedDependencies" -originalDependencies edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz $`

and get the universal dependency, enhanced; but I don't know how to get the NOT enhanced universal dependency on command line. Could anyone help me?

Comment: In "stanford-parser-full-2016-10-31", I try the command line:

java -mx1000m -cp "$scriptdir/:" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -sentences newline -outputFormat "typedDependencies" -originalDependencies edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz $

and get the universal dependency, enhanced; but I don't know how to get the NOT enhanced universal dependency on command line.
Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the latest version of the full Stanford CoreNLP package.

It can be found here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

This is an example command that will produce `json` which has several versions of the dependencies for each sentence.

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -file example-sentence.txt -outputFormat json
```